# How do you exclude negative values in an iterator function?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am putting together a measure of the difference between two datetime values and have ran into negative durations due to bad data, that I need to omit from the calculation.

My DAX function is as follows:

```
Job_length = 
    SUMX ( 
        jobs , 
        DATEDIFF (
            jobs[actualstart] , 
            jobs[actualend] ,
            MINUTE
        )
   )
```

This returns the following output:

[image: image description]

How can I change the formula to skip rows where the iterator expression returns a negative value?

Comment: Bad data should be cleaned upstream in PQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit lacklustre in the sense that it is perhaps the wrong question that is being asked! E.g. why is there data where `actualstart` < `actualend` to begin with? This is something you should fix in ETL prior to loading data into Power BI.

Or better yet, ensure that this is not allowed within your source systems. Perhaps there is a bad setting somewhere in your stack that results in this behavior in the data.

However, to do exactly as you describe you can apply a filter to the table you are iterating over within the `SUMX` function to remove rows that don't comply with the requirement. I have here assumed that only rows where `actualend` is strictly greater than `actualstart` are evaluated:

```
Job_length = 
   SUMX( 
       FILTER ( 
           jobs ,
           [actualstart] < [actualend]
       ),
       DATEDIFF (
            jobs[actualstart], 
            jobs[actualend],
            MINUTE
       )
   )
```

Comment: Yes, I realize this.

As far as the ETL process what can be don there other than manual determining which rows are incorrect? My PowerBI skills are rather lackluster mostly taking courses with no real world application

I just joined the company and am in charge of getting the data lake fixed and usable. I told our devs to enforce data validation in these inputs, no idea why there was none before.

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track! Outside of filtering bad data, or identifying bad data to whomever is in charge of ensuring correct data input, there is not too much worthwhile you can do.